# Sorting array with another array's objects properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a confusing problem right now. The situation is this:

```
let example = [
  {
    name: "First",
    id: 1,
    rank: 1,
    childs: [5,3] // [3,5] -> wrong, because the element which have the id: 3 
//(First's second child), have the rank 2, but with id: 5 (First's first child) have the rank 1.
  },
  {
    name: "First's first child",
    id: 5,
    rank: 1,
    childs: [4,2]
  },
  {
    name: "First's second child",
    id: 3,
    rank: 2,
    childs: [6]
  },
  {
    name: "Second's first child",
    id: 4,
    rank: 1,
    childs: []
  },
  {
    name: "Second's second child",
    id: 2,
    rank: 2,
    childs: []
  },
  {
    name: "Third's first child",
    id: 6,
    rank: 1,
    childs: []
  }
]
```

The `childs` property is an array which shows the element's childs ids (the names of the items shows the relationship between the elements). The `childs` array's elements order must be equal the elements ranks which has the same id the `childs` has.
The problem here is, that the `childs` array's sorting is not always correct, which generates a lot of problems for me. What i need to do is get the element's childs (the `childs` items of the array means the item's id in `example`), search each of them in the `example` array, then sort the `childs` array in order of it's ranks in `example`. So i want to sort `example[i].childs`, depending on the same id'd item's rank in `example`. How is this possible?

Comment: Could you give us an example of the expected output?

Comment: The expected (ideal) output is the example above. The bad output is in the comment. The truth is in my real code i can't really control how the `childs` are sorted. But it must sorted depending on it's rank.

Comment: btw, **childs** does not exists.

Comment: Need to explain what *"sorted depending on it's rank"* even means. That's why expected output would help

Comment: So each `childs` array should maintain the same order as is found in the `example` array? Or they should be sorted ascending by rank?

Comment: I edited the question, i hope it makes it more clear. The `childs` should be sorted by rank.

Comment: Oh, then an easy way would be to replace each id a `childs` array with the actual objects, sort it by `rank`, then replace the objects with the ids, which you have because they're in the object.

Comment: ...though the `5` id appears twice in `examples`.

Comment: Sorry, the first element with id: 5 was id: 2, but i edited for better explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the OP correctly then the output is what the OP example is and the comment was the input. The ordering of the `childs` property is based on the rank of the corresponding element's ranks from the IDs in the `childs` array of the "parent". If that is correct then you can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to search the array for the element matching the child IDs, sort them based on their rank, and then replace the `child` property with the new sorted value.

```js
// First map over the entire example
const sorted = example.map(({childs, ...p}) => ({
  // Copy all of the original element's properties except `childs`
  ...p,
  // Replace `childs` with a sorted array
  childs: childs
    // Find the child element based on the ID
    .map((pid) => example.find(({id: cid}) => pid === cid))
    // Sort the elements based on their rank
    .sort(({rank: a}, {rank: b}) => a - b)
    // Pick out only the `id` value
    .map(({id} = {}) => id)
}));
```

And a working example:

```js
const example = [{
  name: "First",
  id: 1,
  rank: 1,
  childs: [3, 2]
},
{
  name: "First's first child",
  id: 2,
  rank: 1,
  childs: [4, 5]
},
{
  name: "First's second child",
  id: 3,
  rank: 2,
  childs: [6]
},
{
  name: "Second's first child",
  id: 4,
  rank: 1,
  childs: []
},
{
  name: "Second's second child",
  id: 5,
  rank: 2,
  childs: []
},
{
  name: "Third's first child",
  id: 6,
  rank: 1,
  childs: []
}
];

const sorted = example.map(({childs, ...p}) => ({
  ...p,
  childs: childs
    .map((pid) => example.find(({id: cid}) => pid === cid))
    .sort(({rank: a}, {rank: b}) => a - b)
    .map(({id} = {}) => id)
}));
console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Amazing... Sorry, i can't upvote yet, but it helped me a lot. Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: @DorLask No worries. I'm glad I could help. Happy coding. 